# How do you prevent ng-bind-html from adding closing tags?

Tags: angularjs, ng-bind-html

I have two pieces of HTML I need to output the first is an opening tag of a div that represents my header, the second is the closing tag of the div that will represent the footer. Between the two I have dynamic content that I cannot control. I want headerHTML to include the opening div and CSS class and the footer to close the header div to wrap all the content that will be in between.

```
<ng-bind-html ng-bind-html="headerHTML" />

<ng-bind-html ng-bind-html="footerHTML" />
```

So after render it should look like:

```
<div class="myCSSClass">
   A bunch of dynamic content created between the two binds
</div>
```

However, what happens is this:

```
<div class="myCSSClass">
</div>
   A bunch of dynamic content created between the two binds
<div>
</div>
```

The problems is that it is auto adding the closing tag for the headerHTML when its not part of the content. This causes the page to render incorrectly. Is there another way to inject HTML content without it adding closing tag?

Comment: Do you **need** to use `ng-bind-html`? Sounds more like a job for a directive or component.

Comment: @Lex You are right, I ended up using a directive to combine the HTML and it works, will post my full answer later

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under the hood, the `ng-bind-html` directive uses [`Node.appendChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild). This means that it must attach a complete element. If the HTML omits a closing tag, the browser has to close the element. This is the way the DOM works. The browser can't split opening and closing tags between two `.appendChild` operations.

To do what you want, use a component that transcludes contents:

```
app.component("myComponent", {
    bindings: {
        headerHtml: '<',
        footerHtml: '<',
    },
    template: `
        <div class="myCSSClass">
            <div ng-bind-html="$ctrl.headerHtml"></div>
            <div ng-transclude></div>
            <div ng-bind-html="$ctrl.footerHtml"></div>  
       </div>
    `,
    transclude: true
});
```

### Usage:

```
<my-component header-html="headerHTML" footer-html="footerHTML">
   This content will be sandwiched between header and footer.
</my-component>
```

For more information, see

- [AngularJS ng-transclude Directive API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngTransclude).
- [AngularJS Directive Definition Object API Reference - transclude](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-transclude-)

Comment: Can this be done as a directive or does it have to be a component? @georgeawg

Comment: I prematurely marked this as answer, it doesn't appear to work the way described, but rather adds closing tags like the original problem.

Comment: So what problem does that cause for you?

Comment: The headerHTML is an opening tag with css class etc, the footer is a closing tag, I need them to work in conjunction to wrap the contents that are transcluded. But what happens it the headerHTML gets a closing tag added that breaks it into a separate div instead of wrapping.

Comment: The browser can't split opening and closing tags between two `.appendChild` operations.

Comment: This is the technical right answer as this cannot be done with ng-bind-html. I accomplished what I was trying to do via a directive that combines the HTML first. I have re-marked this as correct answer.